# how to get method bb's caller in method bb when it excuted in method aa's block

Tags: ruby, block

The title may not be clear.

here is the code

```
  def self.aa(&block)
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def self.bb
    # i want to get aa info here
    p caller[0]
  end

 #shuriken is a module 
 Shuriken.aa do
  bb
 end
```

i want to get the info of aa when bb is execute in aa block

how to solve this problem or it can be solved? thanks;

Comment: _"i want to get the info of aa"_ – could you be more specific, what exactly do you want in `bb`? And can you describe (in words, not code) what you are trying to achieve? It might help to use a less abstract example (i.e one with actual method names, not `aa` and `bb`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prefix my answer: *This is extremely bad practice. Do not do this in production code.*

Using the [`binding_of_caller`](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) gem, we evaluate the current method two frames up (the first frame up is the `BasicObject#instance_eval`, the second frame up is `Shuriken.aa`):

```
require 'binding_of_caller'

class Shuriken
  def self.aa(&block)
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def self.bb
    the_aa = binding.of_caller(2).eval('method(__method__)')
    puts the_aa
    # => #<Method: Shuriken.aa>
  end
end

Shuriken.aa do
  bb
end
```

Comment: why it is extremely bad practice ?

Comment: Note that `binding_of_caller` is really brutal hack. It reaches inside the private internal implementation details of the execution engine and rips out information it has no business of accessing. That means it is very closely tied to the execution engine, and even its specific version. E.g., it doesn't work on Opal, it doesn't work on MRuby, it doesn't work on IronRuby. On JRuby, it only works when using the interpreter (which almost nobody does, since the performance gained by the aggressively optimizing compiler is one of the main reasons people use JRuby in the first place). …

Comment: … On YARV, it can be broken any moment by any change in the internals, and e.g. doesn't work on YARV 2.2 and 2.3, only 2.1 and below. Oh, I forgot: it also doesn't work on MagLev. And on MacRuby. And on RubyMotion.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: "Brutal hack" is an excellent choice of words. It is the literal answer to the question, but OP, you really, really should not use it.  (BTW, the answer was crafted on 2.3.1p112, and works there.) I am almost hundred percent certain this is an XY problem, and whatever you want to do has a non-hacky solution that does not involve identification of caller.

Comment: @Amadan Any example about 2.3.1p112 ?